# How to use MSMQ (windows) from nodejs(Linux) ?

Tags: node.js, msmq, msmq-wcf

I am trying to use MSMQ(windows) from nodejs(Linux). After searching I find a plugin node-msmq(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-msmq).

But this plugin only helps if the both are on same server.

Any help or suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried to use a queue path that is on another server? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706083(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!  But it will work only in windows to windows.

Comment: If you've tried it and it does not work, add the code to reproduce the issue, the version of the package you are using and the exact error message to your question.

Comment: Is there any workaround to send message to msmq from mac to windows

Comment: It should work if ports are open and if the queue doesn't require validation.
I would make sure that all msmq ports are open using the command telnet host:port. the port list is available [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178517/tcp-ports-udp-ports-and-rpc-ports-that-are-used-by-message-queuing).